# C++ : Aliases in function argument

Tags: c++

I have an issue with the use of aliases in function arguments. Here is my problem.

Let's consider this function definition

```
void thisIsSparta(int& number){
    ...
}
```

at call time, it works perfectly well with the following code :

```
int king = 1;
thisIsSparta(king);
```

but I have a mismatch error when I try this :

```
thisIsSparta(1);
```

I can easily guess that the error occurs because there is simply no variable to alias, hence the error. However, I don't want the programmer to worry about using only one of the two approaches, this second function call should work as fine !

The only solution I see is to create another function with no alias argument, in addition to the first one :

```
void thisIsSparta(int number){

}
```

But this would result in an awful code duplication, and I'm not a huge fan of this.

Furthermore, the program could decide to use this second definition instead of the former when I use a variable. I then loose the interest of the alias, whose purpose is to avoid variable copy.

Does anyone have a solution to my problem ? Indeed, this is a simplified example, in practice I have a generic type in argument for this function, and it could be arbitrarily big. This is why I'd like to use an alias to avoid copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For basic types, just pass by value. It's faster than passing a reference, so ditch the passing by reference and just have

```
void thisIsSparta(int number)
```

For large types, you can only bind temporaries to `const` references, so you can declare the method as

```
void thisIsSortOfSparta(const MyClass& obj)
```

If you're modifying the value inside the function, then passing a temporary as argument doesn't make sense, so the compiler is right to complain, but in case you don't, use the above two options.

Answer (score 2):

Copying a primitive like `int` is completely negligible. It's probably more expensive to pass a reference, for a few reasons.

Secondly, you can overload with

```
const int&
int&
```

This will select the second for all `int` objects, and the first for temporaries and `const int` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with passing the argument by reference is that the function can modify it:

```
void thisIsSparta(int& number) {
    ++number;
}
```

Now, what would `thisIsSparta(1)` do? (No, this isn't ancient FORTRAN, where modifying constants was possible...)

If you want to pass non-modifiable variables, the function has to promise not to modify its argument:

```
void thisIsSparta(const int& number) {
    // whatever
}
```

and, as others have pointed out, for builtin types, passing by value is always preferable to passing by const reference:

```
void thisIsSparta(int number) {
    // whatever
}
```